# Configuration file per package in SpringBoot what performance impact will it have?

Tags: spring-boot

I want to create bean config file per each package where it is necessary  like this:

```
   /user
     - ... classes and interfaces here
     - UserBeanConfig
     /policy
          - ... classes and interfaces here
          - UserPolicyBeanConfig
```

where bean config is just:

```
@Configuration
class MyBeanConfig {

    @Bean
    MyBean myBean() {
       retrun new MyBean()
    }  
   
    ... more beans
```

I want to understand how big performance impact this can have for a
SpringBoot app?
Will this be significant or irrelevant?